# Drop Down Menu Where All the Elements are Check Boxes

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to create a drop-down menu where all the options in the drop menu are check boxes. The motivation here is so that the user can easily select multiple options in the drop-down. Based on what they select I need to parametrize the form and make an Ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of these two -

http://www.sexyselect.net

or

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-asmselect/

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for [jQuery Multiselect](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20multiselect) returned [a jQuery UI plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) as the first result.

Answer (score 0):

Try Dropdown Checklist: http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Answer (score 0):

`<label>` elements make it incredibly simple to make menus like this.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="item-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="1" /> 
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="item-2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="2" /> 
      <span>Item 2</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="item-3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="3" /> 
      <span>Item 3</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function is very useful for sending [$_POST requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to the server.

Note that adding padding to your `<li>` elements or margin to your `<label>` will make this method less effective.

Comment: I want these elements hover to appear as a drop-down menu.

Comment: The `<ul>` element would be your drop-down menu.

Comment: For me it is not creating a drop-down:http://jsfiddle.net/KJGB7/. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This solution is more for a custom-built menu. Given your apparent level of knowledge in HTML/CSS, I'd probably recommend using a plugin.